# Is ajax call did not support php include?

Tags: php, ajax

Sorry for changing the question

I'm trying to include another php file inside php, my code is like this

[Ajax mysqli not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646464/ajax-mysqli-not-working/32646495#32646495)

The difference is

I change `"$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");" with "include 'admin/connection.php';"`

Without include it's working, but, after adding include it's keep giving me error :(

Is it just me, my code is wrong or ajax didn't support php include?

Comment: what was the location of connection file compared to the page called for ajax

Comment: The location is admin/connection.php, so on folder after ajax.

Comment: Please check the path of include 'admin/connection.php';

Comment: I already did and it's the correct path :(

Comment: I have a same problem as you right now. So have you got an answer?

Answer (score 1):

if 'admin/connection.php' contains Connection code to DB

- use require [require PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)  instead of include

*require  will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.*

```
require('admin/connection.php');
```

and if your server is not connected to db how can you expect to run sql query

Comment: I did, still no change :( keep giving me error "username wrong :(" sorry I already give the detail on question :(

Comment: you say it  " keep giving me error "username wrong"  so you got the bug your username is wrong check it out

Comment: No :( sorry, I mean "Username password error" :( I already type the right password and it's working without the include quote :(

Comment: is your password blank and username is root and db name is whatever?
check php Manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php
Or this http://codular.com/php-mysqli OR google "How to connect to mysql Db in php"

Comment: Yes it is :) it's blank :) i haven't change my xampp password :) but it's the include :( without include it's working good :( the connection script is just this "$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");" the same, so why :( ?